# Ubuntu LTS install stuck "Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1)"

Tags: 20.04, lts

Installing Ubuntu LTS offline via usb, and get stopped at `Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1)` for a long period of time.

If I run the installer online, I seem to get stuck at the message `subiquity/late/run`.

I've let it run for a while in both scenarios, I don't think I am being impatient because nothing is happening.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Is the installation media valid? Does it pass integrity checks? Is your motherboard BIOS up-to-date?